# writing a while loop statement in python while eliminating Type error

Tags: python, while-loop, integer, typeerror

For the following exercise:
Write a program to keep asking for a number until you enter a negative number. At the end, print the sum of all entered numbers.

I can do this using a while loop and the 'if/ else statement' which works well.

```
num = 0
v = int

while True:
print('please enter number')
v = int(input())
if v > 0:
    num = num + v
else:
    print('you have entered a negative number')
    num = num + v
    break

print('total number is ' + str(num))
```

But if i want to write the program using only while loop i.e. no if/else statement attached i get a TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'int'
See my code below:

```
num = 0
v = int

while v >= 0:
    print('please enter number')
    v = int(input())
    num = num + v

print('you have entered a negative number')
num = num + v
print('total number is ' + str(num))
```

I think the issue might have to do with the way i've initialised the variables here. Please help.

Comment: You have `v = int` followed immediately by checking the condition `v >= 0`. So you're checking the condition `int >= 0`, which doesn't mean anything. What should that condition evaluate to? How could you initialise `v` in order to achieve that?

Comment: What is `v = int` meant to accomplish?

Comment: Even if you didn't get the error, your second code would not be correct, since it includes the negative number in the sum.

Comment: the reason for initialising as  v = int  was to state that it is an integer variable. How else would I initialise it then please? it makes sense now that I have tried to compare a type with an integer in the while condition. I also did not want to initialise  v = 0 .

Comment: In Python you don't initialise variables with a type. `v = int` is an assignment expression, it assigns the _value_ `int` (a constructor for integers) to variable `v`.  Variables should be initialised with a _value_ i.e. `v = 0`. We can also _annotate_ it with a type at that time, like `v: int = 0`.

Comment: There is not really a concept of a "declared but uninitialised" variable in Python, you can write `v: int` by itself but it's a no-op and on the next line it will be as if `v` has not been defined. If you don't want to use `0` as initial value you can use `None` (like null in other langs) to have a var which is declared but has "no value" (although it does have a value, it's value is `None`)

Comment: awesome stuff @anentropic. I have learnt quite a few things from you today. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v = int` is assigning `v` to a `type`, therefore when `while` check for `v >= 0` it will raise a TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'int'

If you didn't want to assign `v = 0`, you can use walrus operator (`:=`) to assign a value to a variable and return that value in the same expression (Python 3.8+)

```
num = 0
while (v := int(input('please enter number\n'))) >= 0:
    num += v
print('you have entered a negative number')
print('total number is ' + str(num))
```

Answer (score 1):

For integer numbers as input you can modify your code as following:

```
num = 0
v = 0

while v >= 0:
    v = int(input('please enter a number: '))
    num += v
print('you have entered a negative number')
num += v
print(f'total number is {num}')
```